# Regex : one mandatory word, two optionnals

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regex who match these criterias

The word FIRST is mandatory ; it can appear only once

The word SECOND can appear zero or one time

The word THIRD can appear zero or one time

I tried this

```
^(?=.*?(FIRST))(?=.*?(SECOND))(?=.*?(THIRD))
```

And this

```
^(?=.*?(FIRST))(?=.*?(SECOND{0,1}))(?=.*?(THIRD{0,1}))
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

EDIT:
The words can be in any order.

This should match :

> Here is FIRST and THIRD
>
> SECOND and FIRST, THIRD !
>
> THIRD

This should not :

> SECOND SECOND FIRST //Second appear twice
>
> SECOND THIRD // First is mandatory

Comment: Can you give an example, where it does not work?

Comment: Looking at your expressions you seem to have more conditions that you won't tell us about.  Do these words have to be in a specific oder? And besides why do you assert the position at the start of a string with ^ and then optionally skip any charactr up to the word FIRST?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but isn't this just `^FIRST(SECOND)?(THIRD)?$` The question mark `?` is a shorthand for `{0,1}`. When you say you "it doesn't work", be more specific. _Which_ input is misclassified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply reverse logic: FIRST, SECOND and THIRD cannot appear 2 or more times, but there must be at least one FIRST:

```
^(?!.*THIRD.*THIRD)(?!.*SECOND.*SECOND)(?!.*FIRST.*FIRST)(?=.*FIRST)
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO5jS2/4)

To match whole words, use `\b` word boundary around the words. If you need to match newline symbols, do not forget the DOTALL/singleline modifier (in most regex falvors, it is `/s`).

If FIRST should come before SECOND, and SECOND should come before THIRD, use two more lookaheads:

```
^(?!.*THIRD.*(?:SECOND|FIRST)) # SECOND or FIRST cannot appear after THIRD
(?!.*SECOND.*FIRST)            # SECOND cannot appear before FIRST
(?!.*THIRD.*THIRD)             # THIRD can only appear one or zero times
(?!.*SECOND.*SECOND)           # SECOND can only appear one or zero times
(?!.*FIRST.*FIRST )            # FIRST can only appear one or zero times
(?=.*FIRST)                    # However, FIRST must appear at least once
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO5jS2/4)

Comment: would you be so kind to show how to add ordering to this? I.e. `FIRST` comes first, then `SECOND`, then `THIRD`?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Note that FIRST (1 occurrence only) can be checked with two tempered greedy token (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO5jS2/3)), but I think 2 separate lookaheads are more readable.

Comment: When I look on this I think `so simple`, but when I was trying to solve it I could not to. Probably that is the second stage of mastering regexes. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Oh thank you it worked !! Feeling a bit frustrated for not thinking about your reverse logic ! Anyway, thank you :)